# Extract a substring from a text string in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract a substring from a text string in postgresql. The column name of the text string is URL and I am using the subtring function to define a regex that will return only the portion that I want:

```
SELECT
substring('user_latitude=.*user_' from URL)
FROM my_table
limit 10
```

When I execute this query, I am greeted with the following response:

> SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Not implemented
>    Detail:
>
> ---
>
> error:  Not implemented
>    code:      1001
>    context:   'false' - Function substring(text,text) not implemented - use REGEXP_SUBSTR instead
>    query:     258128
>    location:  cg_expr.cpp:4265
>    process:   padbmaster [pid=52019]
>
> ---
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Not implemented
>    Detail:
>
> ---
>
> error:  Not implemented
>    code:      1001
>    context:   'false' - Function substring(text,text) not implemented - use >REGEXP_SUBSTR instead
>    query:     258128
>    location:  cg_expr.cpp:4265
>    process:   padbmaster [pid=52019]
>
> ---

However, REGEXP_SUBSTR does not appear to be a native function, and does not work.

Is there a way to extract a value from a string in POSTGRES?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Amazon Redshift you are running is built on Postgres 8.0.2 and furthermore lot of the Postgres functions [is not supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html), it is good to take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html) to see what actually is available.

The [SUBSTRING](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUBSTRING.html) function has a signature different to how you have used it, it should be something like this:

```
select
substring(URL from 14)
from my_table
limit 10
```

This would yield the portion of `URL` from the 14th character to the end.

Alternatively, if not even this version of SUBSTRING is supported, try using the suggested [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html):

```
select
regexp_substr(URL, '=.*')
from my_table
limit 10
```

This would return the portion of `URL` from '=' onward.